# angry birds slingshot in sprite kit Xcode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i am making a game on Xcode using sprite kit it is and i need to add an angry bird slingshot like to the ball, i don't know how can i apply it

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    sprite.size.height = 50
    sprite.size.width = 50
    sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    sprite.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    sprite.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    sprite.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
    sprite.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
    sprite.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0
    self.addChild(sprite)

    // 1. Create a physics body that borders the screen
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    // 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
    borderBody.friction = 0
    // 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the ball an impulse and the gravitiy will do the rest.

Comment: How can this be done, can you give me more information, i want it to be angry bird slingshot style

Comment: You first need to make a spritenode from the ball